# Custom date format where type will be object and instance of date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-formatting

I am receiving date from back end in `2017-03-02T08:12:22.997000+00:00` this format.

To display this date in specified format I am doing
`new Date('2017-03-02T08:12:22.997000+00:00').toLocaleString()` that gives `3/2/2017, 1:42:22 PM`

There's one functionality which is sorting this formatted output.
Agenda is to sort the output based on 'date' type. But since I am using `toLocaleString()` method for formatting, sorting is done based on 'string' type.

Is there any solution where I can achieve `3/2/2017, 1:42:22 PM` format and type will be a Date object?

Or a date format where I can see date along with time excluding GMT part? (like `toUTCString()`)

Or any method from moment will work?

Comment: have a look over this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-datetime-string-in-javascript

Comment: This seems to be a combination of "[*how do I parse an ISO 8601 string to a date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569/help-parsing-iso-8601-date-in-javascript)", "[*how do I sort dates*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735854/how-to-return-the-lowest-date-value-and-highest-date-value-from-an-array-in-java/26736729#26736729)" and "[*how do I format a date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript?s=1|8.9678)". Since the initial dates are strings, you can sort those, then use a Date object for formatting.

Comment: Note that *toLocaleString* is entirely implementation dependent and produces different results in different hosts.

Comment: any comment or feedback on my solution @ManjiM

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment.js which will give you moment object.

first convert date to IsoDate as moment.js latest version has deprecated moment constructor with illegal date string ( [more info here )](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407%20for%20more%20info.)

```
var isoDate = new Date('2017-03-02T08:12:22.997000+00:00').toISOString(),
    formatedDate = moment(isoDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM:SS A');
```

// formatedDate : "02/03/2017, 13:03:99 PM"

you may use Timezone for better handling of time -

```
moment(isoDate).tz('timezoneValue').format('DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM:SS A');
```