# How to get the maximum time and minimum time in an array

Tags: javascript

```
let departDateArr=['2020-10-13 12:00','2020-10-03 13:00','2020-10-13 8:00','2020-10-16 20:00']

let arriveDateArr=['2022-12-20 00:00','2022-12-20 12:20','2022-12-19 12:20','2022-12-08 12:20']
```

I want to retrieve the minimum time in the departDateArr array

I want to retrieve the maximum time in the arraveDateArr array

How to get the desired time data through time comparison ？

Comment: also: [How to return the lowest date value and highest date value from an array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735854/how-to-return-the-lowest-date-value-and-highest-date-value-from-an-array-in-java)

Comment: If the IOS system does not support the 2020-10-13 format, how should it be converted？

Comment: Please update the question with the expected results. E.G.  for earliest departure do  you require  `2020-10-13 8:00` as the earliest time of departure, or `2020-10-03 13:00` as the earliest time and date of departure.

Comment: 2020-10-03 13:00  At the earliest, I'm sorry, but my statement may not be very clear

Answer (score 2):

Your times are in a format that can be compared lexicographically, so you can simply use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and string comparison to get the maximum or minimum.

```js
let departDateArr=['2020-10-13 12:00','2020-10-03 13:00','2020-10-13 8:00','2020-10-16 20:00'];
let arriveDateArr=['2022-12-20 00:00','2022-12-20 12:20','2022-12-19 12:20','2022-12-08 12:20'];
let minDepart = departDateArr.reduce((a,b)=>b<a?b:a);
let maxArrive = arriveDateArr.reduce((a,b)=>b>a?b:a);
console.log(minDepart);
console.log(maxArrive);
```

Comment: 11 year duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143443/13762301

Comment: Does this find the minimum and maximum times, or the earliest/latest date and time? I'm not sure what OP wants.

Comment: @traktor I assumed the question was asking for the earliest or latest time.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/a/26735940/13762301 which notes the lexicographic nature of ISO date strings